# Flex 4 Tree Lazy Loading

Tags: apache-flex

I have to create a tree in Flex 4, which will populate the nodes from the remote object.
My tree structure would be something like this
Site 1
 --Eqpt 1
 --Eqpt 2
Site 2
 -- Eqpt x
 -- Eqpt y

I will be fetching the values form the Java RemoteObject using hibernate and from Site Table and eqpt table.

One easy way i can think of creating a xml from table and return to flex and assign the data provider of a tree.

Or is there any easy way which through i can add Sites first in the tree and eqpts shall be loaded at the any particular site click. I want to implement lazy loading.

Thanks in advance.
Aj

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of articles and implementations out there for lazy loaded trees, here are a few links for you:

http://blogs.adobe.com/aharui/2008/12/tree_and_lazy_or_paged_data_1.html

http://plummersmind.blogspot.com/2009/01/better-flex-tree.html

http://flexdiary.blogspot.com/2009/01/lazy-loading-tree-example-file-posted.html

Hope that helps.

Comment: Note that my subdomain got nuked. My apologies for everyone who tried to see this code while it was down. It has been restored.